# Spring MVC broken request parameter handling

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I need to proxy raw HTTP request data to another HTTP endpoint, as-is.

Spring MVC mutates the `HttpServletRequest` instance and also consumes the `request.getInputStream()` before I get a chance to inspect it in my controller method and it ends up as an empty stream.

Furthermore, Spring MVC conflates the query-string parameters with the POST body parameters, but only when the input `Content-Type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. For correct proxying behavior, this must not be done. The HTTP endpoint being proxied to is sensitive to maintaining separate query-string vs. POST body parameters.

Since I cannot rely on Spring MVC to not corrupt the incoming request state, I need to bypass MVC entirely and register an independent `Servlet` of my own where I need access to the raw HTTP input, unmodified by Spring.

My application is a Spring Boot (1.2.5) application deployed to Tomcat 8 as a WAR but with a `static void main` to start embedded Tomcat 8 on development machines.

How do I create an independent `Servlet` to handle this proxy logic? I've tried `ServletRegistrationBean` to register the servlet but this still corrupts the incoming request with Spring's default filters. I need to exclude these filters and start afresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get around the initial problem of MVC consuming the POST body by disabling the `HiddenHttpMethodFilter`.

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean hiddenHttpMethodFilterRegistration(HiddenHttpMethodFilter filter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
    registration.setFilter(filter);
    registration.setEnabled(false);
    return registration;
}
```